# In debug mode I can see extra array list elements and are initialized to zero

Tags: java, jdbc, arraylist

I am fetching some data from database using simple jdbc call and when I am debugging my application, it is showing some extra record which are null.

[image]

Actual size of my list should be 138 but its initializing 171 as array size.

[image]

As I am using collection named LDCBeanCollection which extends ArrayList and implements BaseDTO which is Serializable

`public class LDCBeanCollection extends ArrayList implements BaseDTO`

```
public interface BaseDTO extends Serializable
```

**Why this problem is occuring. Am I missing something ?**

**How can I overcome this problem?**

Comment: Size of list != size of array, basically.

Comment: Thanks Jon - Does it affects the performance of my application? If I am fetching more records like in thousands or lakhs.

Comment: It will only take up some extra memory - but just 4 or 8 bytes per "spare" element of the array, and doing so has saved a lot of copying along the way. (It's worth being aware that "lakh" is a term which isn't used in most English-speaking countries. I know what you mean, but you may wish to spell it out as "hundreds of thousands" in general on Stack Overflow.)

Comment: @ahishraaj ... this null value is arise due to load factor of arraylist. I think you should read about load factor and you will understand by it yourself

Answer (score 5, accepted):

An `ArrayList` internally manages a backing array that is usually larger than the current size.  Since `ArrayList` is a variable-length list the array size is managed internally so it doesn't have to be reallocated each time you add an element.  That would be extremely expensive.  When the list overflows (you add more elements that currently fit) the backing array size is `incremented by 1.5 times than original size` to allow for future expansion.

In other words, there will almost always be extra unused elements at the end of the backing array, and they only consume one reference per entry.

http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/8u40-b25/java/util/ArrayList.java#ArrayList.grow%28int%29

If you are concerned about the extra elements, don't be. The class manages things so they are never seen to be part of the list.

Comment: Does it affects the performance of my application? If I am fetching more records like in thousands or lakhs.

Comment: Size is not doubled, but incremented by 1.5 times then original array length.

Comment: Ah. Used to be double at some point in the past.  The salient point is that the increase is geometric. Thanks for adding the grepcode link.  Grepcode is an incredibly valuable resource :-)

Comment: @ashishraaj .. yes it affects to performance.you should at last to do is arraylist.trimToSize();

Comment: @Darshit No, it does not affect performance.  It takes up a little extra memory.  Unless the list contains all the elements it will ever contain, trimming it will _worsen_ performance as it will require re-allocating the array and copying all the references when a new element is added.

Comment: @JimGarrison.. yes i googled it and you are right.. thanks for clearing my concept :)